# OleDbException 'unspecified error'

Tags: vb.net, oledbexception

So, i get the OleDBException "unspecified error" whenever the function below hits the `dataAdapter.SelectCommand = dbcommand` line.

I have tried adding `dbcommand.connection.close()` and `dbcommand.connection.dispose()` but neither fixed the problem.

I assume that this error would happen every time i try to connect with the DB but this is just the first function that does so in my code, so this is where the error is first occuring.

I have read online that MySQL will eventually clear out old connections after a while, if this is true, then i should just have to wait..but i dont want to keep waiting for nothing to happen.

```
    Function GetOrders(ByVal _numberrecords As Long) As DataTable
    Dim TaxConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Database")
    Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(TaxConnStr)
    Try
        'Code to get orders in call status. Sort oldest to newest
        ' dbConnection.Open()
        Dim queryString As String
        queryString = "SELECT TOP " & _numberrecords & " Orders.Control_Number, Orders.State, Orders.County, Orders.Status, Orders.ZipCode, Orders.OrderNumber, Orders.Client, Orders.Department "
        queryString += "FROM Orders "
        queryString += "WHERE(((Orders.Status) = 'Tax Cert Call' Or (Orders.Status) = 'Online')) "
        queryString += "ORDER BY Orders.Date_Received;"
        Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
        dbCommand.CommandText = queryString
        dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection
        'dbCommand.Connection.Close()
        'dbCommand.Connection.Dispose()
        'dbCommand.Dispose()
        Dim dataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = dbCommand
        Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
        If dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count >= 1 Then
            GetOrders = dataSet.Tables(0)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        myLogger.Log(ex.Message)
    Finally
        dbConnection.Close()

        dbConnection.Dispose()
    End Try


End Function
```

Comment: What is the value of _numberrecords? And, you talk about MySql, but are you using MS-Access?

Comment: _numberRecords = 1 & yea, we are using MS Access, my bad.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the same query with the Access interface?

Comment: Yep, that works just fine. I also did "Compact & Repair" on the DB and that didn't fix anything. It's such a vague error - makes it hard to debug.

Comment: Can't find anything wrong. Just in case you have no record the function doesn't return anything, but this is not the problem. As a last thing, I will try to open explicitly the connection before assigning the object to the command. Also, if you like, you could post a sample database online so we could try your code.